# Firebird/Interbase SQL query in php file

Tags: php, firebird

I have the following query in a PHP file which works fine and returns the data it should

```sql
SELECT
'NZ' AS ORDERORIGIN,
'Assembly' as ORDERTYPE,
ORDERNUMBER,
ITEMDESCRIPTION AS ORDERDESCRIPTION
FROM ASSEMBLYHEADER AH
WHERE AH.ORDERSTATUS IN ('InProgress','Open')
```

When I add to the query, as below,

```sql
SELECT
    'NZ' AS ORDERORIGIN,
    'Assembly' as ORDERTYPE,
    ORDERNUMBER,
    ITEMDESCRIPTION AS ORDERDESCRIPTION
FROM ASSEMBLYHEADER AH
WHERE AH.ORDERSTATUS IN ('InProgress','Open')
UNION
SELECT
    'NZ' AS ORDERORIGIN,
    'Non-Charge' as ORDERTYPE,
    COSTCENTRECODE AS ORDERNUMBER,
    'NO ORDER DESCRIPTION' AS ORDERDESCRIPTION
FROM COSTCENTREMASTER
WHERE COSTCENTRECODE IN ('STK','ADM','CL','DR','HS','ME','STR','SUP','CAD','STQC','STDR','STOR','L5S','LKA','ECR','GENG','GSALE','TECH','GRAD','GMAR','GWAR','EUS','SUS','ASPP')
ORDER BY 3"
```

then I get an error *"ibase_fetch_assoc(): Malformed string in row 220"*. Row 220 in the PHP file is

```
while ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

When I use the same query elsewhere it works perfectly fine. The error appears on the webpage not the console.

When I look up *"malformed string"* there is mention about the character set. In the `<Header>` of the PHP I have `<meta charset="utf-8">`.
I tried replacing '' with 'No Order Description', but that didn't work.
The extra data from the extended SQL statement is below. No unusual characters. Anything else I should be checking?

```
NZ  Non-Charge  ADM
NZ  Non-Charge  ASPP
NZ  Non-Charge  CAD
NZ  Non-Charge  CL
NZ  Non-Charge  DR
NZ  Non-Charge  ECR
NZ  Non-Charge  EUS
NZ  Non-Charge  GENG
NZ  Non-Charge  GMAR
NZ  Non-Charge  GRAD
NZ  Non-Charge  GSALE
NZ  Non-Charge  GWAR
NZ  Non-Charge  HS
NZ  Non-Charge  L5S
NZ  Non-Charge  LKA
NZ  Non-Charge  ME
NZ  Non-Charge  STDR
NZ  Non-Charge  STK
NZ  Non-Charge  STOR
NZ  Non-Charge  STQC
NZ  Non-Charge  STR
NZ  Non-Charge  SUP
NZ  Non-Charge  SUS
NZ  Non-Charge  TECH
```

Comment: Maybe the row 220 mentioned in the error to relate to the row received from the database, not the line in your PHP file. In any case, we really need a [mre] for this.

Answer (score -1):

To overcome the issue I created 3 separate queries and combined the results then added them to the UL one at a time. It doesn't matter that the list is not ordered overall. Still don't know what caused the original problem, but I have a solution.